# Time.now differs from created_at in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This question is not related to timezones-- it's about the minutes and seconds.  What is the source for Time.now and what is the source for the created_at timestamp?

One of the times is off by 2 minutes in production.  In thing_controller.rb:

```
@thing.create(:name => "Bob")
puts Time.now
puts @thing.created_at.to_time
```

The production log on Heroku shows this (2-minute difference) even though these events actually happen immediately after each other:

```
2015-01-22T23:25:20.563749+00:00 app[web.2]: 2015-01-22 23:25:20 +0000
2015-01-22T23:25:20.563789+00:00 app[web.2]: 2015-01-22 23:23:26 UTC
```

When run in development mode locally, the log shows just a 3 second-difference:

```
2015-01-22 18:39:11 -0500
2015-01-22 23:39:08 UTC
```

This is Rails 3.2.  Many thanks for your help!